# How to query external SQL Server databases and displays the result in SharePoint list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, database-connection

I am trying to connect to external SQL database and want to show up select query data in SharePoint list.
I did create External Content Type but that doesn't allow me to use custom query for the table.
I know there are some third party tool. I was wondering is there any easier way of doing this.

Thanks,

Rishabh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to create a SQL table view and then connect to it via BCS (this will require use of SharePoint Designer). Business Data Connectivity Service needs to be created in Central Administration.

There is an extensive article on this here: http://prairiedeveloper.com/2016/01/sharepoint-business-connectivity-service-create-external-content-type-and-external-list/

Comment: Thanks Paul, I think creating view would be best option. As I don't want third party web part to use.